# counting number of new values per month in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a huge list(pandas dataframe) that looks like this

```
            user    userID    
Date    
1/1/2018    Annual    12345
1/3/2018    Annual    12345
1/5/2018    One Time  
1/11/2018   One Time   
1/12/2018   One Time   
1/13/2018   Annual    98765
.
.
2/1/2018    Annual    12345
2/3/2018    Annual    12345
2/5/2018    One Time  
2/11/2018   One Time   
2/12/2018   One Time   
2/13/2018   Annual    98765
```

This is a list of history of user activities. Every time someone uses this service, it is recorded. There are annual membership holders and one time users.

What I want to do is counting number of new annual membership purchases per month.

Membership is valid for one year so I assume if a membership is purchased on 1/1/2017, userID 11111 is valid until 12/31/2017. In the example list above, user 12345 used the service twice but the second one shouldnt count because user 12345 purchased annual membership on 1/1/2018. Similarly, user 12345s activity on 2/1/2018 shouldnt count as a new membership purchase because it was purchased on 1/1/2017.

And it is also assumed that annual membership was purchased when they used their first service as an annual membership holder.(userID 12345 purchased his/her membership on 1/1/2018)

EDIT

example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import randint
from random import randrange
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime.strptime('1/1/2017', '%m/%d/%Y')
end = datetime.strptime('12/31/2017', '%m/%d/%Y')

def random_date(start, end):
    delta = end - start
    int_delta = (delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60) + delta.seconds
    random_second = randrange(int_delta)
    return start + timedelta(seconds=random_second)

userIDs = []
dates = []
userType = []

for i in range(10000):
    userIDs.append( randint(100, 999))
    dates.append( random_date(start, end) )
    userType.append( randint(1, 2) )

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': userIDs, 'date':dates, 'type': userType})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace = True)
```

Comment: You should include some example data in a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try groupings (by year and userID, then by year and month), but working with the expiry date would require many maneuvers. I believe a more mechanical solution can handle the problem pretty straightforward.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


count = {}  # month's number of subscriptions
since = {}  # member's date of subscription
for i, r in df[df.type==1].sort_values('date').iterrows():
    if r.ID in since and r.date < since[r.ID] + relativedelta(years=1):
        continue  # valid member, not counting
    since[r.ID] = r.date

    ym = r.date.year, r.date.month
    count[ym] = count.setdefault(ym, 0) + 1
```

I prefer not to consider date as index, because two members should be able to adhere at the same time.

Printing `count` in order gives something like:

```
(2017, 1) 94
(2017, 2) 7
(2018, 1) 76
(2018, 2) 20
(2018, 3) 5
(2019, 1) 50
(2019, 2) 39
(2019, 3) 10
(2019, 4) 2
```